# Ubuntu 14.04 HOST - Windows 10 GUEST - VirtualBox Resolution Issue

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Running Ubuntu 14.04 as the host. Got version 5.0.26 of VirtualBox and I'm running a Windows 10 as the guest os.

Like all of the other threads, the resolution will not go above a certain setting. I've installed and tried both 5.0.26 and 5.0.10 guest additions on the guest os. I've also enabled 2d, 3d acceleration and have 256mb video memory on the options for the vm.

[image]

[image]

The option on the host exists, but when I click on for example 1920x1080 nothing happens to the guest os.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Wow. I rolled back the driver in the guest os and restarted the vm. Fixed the issue. Weird as ****.